# node.isAncestor is not a function

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

When i'm run **npm run build:ssr** command, it return app url successfully.See below

`Node server listening on http://localhost:4000`

While hitting the url in browser, i get the following error.

```
ERROR TypeError: node.isAncestor is not a function
    at DocumentFragment._ensureInsertValid (D:\xampp\htdocs\abc\dist\server.js:80983:14)
    at DocumentFragment.insertBefore (D:\xampp\htdocs\abc\dist\server.js:81113:12)
    at DocumentFragment.value (D:\xampp\htdocs\abc\dist\server.js:81129:17)
    at buildFragment (D:\xampp\htdocs\abc\dist\server.js:305246:26)
    at domManip (D:\xampp\htdocs\abc\dist\server.js:306281:14)
    at jQuery.fn.init.append (D:\xampp\htdocs\abc\dist\server.js:306472:10)
    at Owl.initializeStage (D:\xampp\htdocs\abc\dist\server.js:382409:17)
    at Owl.initialize (D:\xampp\htdocs\abc\dist\server.js:382471:8)
    at new Owl
```

Comment: Paste verbose texts instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using owl carousel, Owl is using jQuery and it's not supported in SSR and cannot be rendered on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have resolved this issue. Please follow the below steps.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { OwlCarousel } from 'ngx-owl-carousel';

export class HomeComponent { 

    @ViewChild('owlElement') owlElement: OwlCarousel;

    ngOnInit() {

       this.owlElement.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [3000]);
    }

}
```

```
<owl-carousel #owlElement
       [items]="images"
       [options]="sliderOption"
       [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'row', 'sliding']">

       <div class="item landing-slider-banner" *ngFor="let image of images">
           <div class="container">

           </div>
       </div>
</owl-carousel>
```